# Remove spaces and quotes outside words and leave one space between words

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with with quotes and spaces like`' TEST   123  '` or  `"  TEST  123  "`. How can I remove spaces and quotes outside words and leave one space between words. Expected result: `TEST 123`

Comment: Please share with us what you've tried

Comment: here is the logic for you, `trim`, `split`, `trim`, `join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
^[ '"]+|[ '"]+$|( ){2,}
```

And replace it wit `$1` where `$1` captures a single space but of instance where there are two or more spaces.

Here, `^[ '"]+` matches any space or single or double quote one or more from start of string and similarly `[ '"]+$` also matches any space or single or doublequote one or more at the end of string and gets replaced with empty string where as when `( ){2,}` matches, which remains to be matched in the middle of string, gets replaced with a single space as captured in group1.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Swsi2X/1)**

Sample JS demo,

```js
var arr = ["' TEST   123  '",'"  TEST  123  "'];

for (s of arr) {
 console.log(s + " --> " + s.replace(/^[ '"]+|[ '"]+$|( ){2,}/g,'$1'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[remove extra spaces in string javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974664/remove-extra-spaces-in-string-javascript)

newString = string.replace(/\s+/g,''); // "thiscontainsspaces"

newString = string.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim();

Comment: string contains double or single quotes, not only spaces

Comment: single quotes...you basically replacing anything that fits the regular expression with a blank value

Comment: newString = string.replace(/[ '"]+/g, ' ').trim()   - it leaves spaces before word